# Flutter AdMob Ad Placement

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I'm trying to find a way to place an AdMob ad at the top of my widget tree.  The best way I thought of doing this was to try to place it in the flexible space inside the appbar. The spacing isn't quite how I want it as the ad is appearing behind the title, leading, and trailing widgets on the appbar. Is there any way to move the ad up so it's not placed behind the content of the appbar? If not, is there a way I can place the ad outside the appbar and have it appear above a scaffold (tried wrapping the scaffold in the column to achieve this and didn't work)?

Image of appbar:
[image: Image of appbar]

```
    AppBar returnAppBarForHomePagesTest(
    BuildContext context,
    String page_header,
    localUser local_user,
    Function updateUserState,
    bool using_default_image,
    String profile_pic,
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffold_key,
    BannerAd ad,
    bool ad_loaded) {
  return AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: 100,
    flexibleSpace: ad_loaded /// TRYING TO PLACE AD HERE
    ? Container(
      child: AdWidget( 
        ad: ad,
      ),
      width: ad.size.width.toDouble(),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    )
    : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: HEADER_FOOTER_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(page_header,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: PRIMARY_PAGE_HEADER_SIZE,
          color: Colors.white,
        )),
    leadingWidth: 35,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    leading: Transform.translate(
      offset: const Offset(8, 0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          globals.GlobalVars()
              .navigatorKey
              .currentState
              ?.pushNamed(EditProfile.route_name, arguments: local_user)
              .then((value) {
            if (value != null) {
              updateUserState(value);
            }
          });
        },
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: using_default_image
              ? AssetImage(profile_pic) as ImageProvider
              : NetworkImage(profile_pic),
          radius: 5,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.settings_outlined,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 35,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          scaffold_key.currentState?.openDrawer(); // do something
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to wrap your `Scaffold` in a `Stack`

```
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            ...
          ),
          body: ...
        ),
        if (showAd) 
          //Your ad here
          Container(
            height: kToolbarHeight,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child : ...
          ),
      ],
    );
```

Here is a [working gist you can try](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7c2cd6175e9d7d1dcb1a1aa5d627de4e)